# A difficulty in understanding theorem 4.2 in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The theorem is given in the following picture:

[image]

Part of it's proof is given in the following picture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

1-But I did not understand in the part of the proof  why for each $k$ we have the first equality(from the left for a reader in front of the computer screeen) in the third line, could anyone explain this for me please?

2-It is not clear for me where is the proof of uniqueness, could anyone clarify this for me please?

3-Also it is not clear for me at all how he proved conversely,could anyone clarify this for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left<\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}\varphi_{j},\varphi_{k}\right>=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}\left<\varphi_{j},\varphi_{k}\right>=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}\delta_{j,k}=a_{k}$, where the very definition of orthonormal says that $\left<\varphi_{i},\varphi_{j}\right>=\delta_{i,j}$ which is equal to $1$ if $i=j$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: I mean the first equality from the left not from the right.

Comment: That is a strategy, to assume such $w$ exists first and figure out the $a_{j}$. Any element in $M$ can be written as a finite linear combination, because we want the orthogonal to be valid, simply assume that is the case, then we can solve for $a_{j}$, which is the inner product with each $\varphi_{j}$.

Comment: I have edited my question .... could you please answer my remaining questions if you have time ?

Comment: I guessed you didn't paste the proof of the part of uniqueness?

Comment: okay I will add a picture..... what about conversely, why $<v-w,z> = 0$?

Comment: Can you tell me the name of the book? It seems that you have pasted wrong picture, the part repeats so I have no clue. But that does not matter, I can search for the book, and explain to you.

Comment: "Basic operator theory " Israel Gohberg

Comment: No the new picture is added at the beginning not at the end.

Comment: The uniqueness part, I think the crucial is why $\left<v-w,w-z\right>=0$, for then you can apply Pythagorean, but you have posted another question and someone else has answered you, so it shouldn't be a problem right now.